# Is an IntentService's onStartCommand(..) method thread safe?

Tags: android, thread-safety, intentservice

I have an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class that can be started from various places in a complex application - Activities, background Threads, other Services. I'd like to keep a counter of how many times the service was invoked. I use a private int variable within my IntentService class to keep track of that, I increment it from my [onStartCommand(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) method.

It just occured to me, as the onStartCommand(...) method can be called from various asynchronous threads, that this might not be a thread-safe solution. So the question is, do I need to wrap the access to this counter variable in a synchronized block, or does the IntentService implementation of onStartCommand(...) takes care of this for me?

As a note, I know I could safely increment the variable from [onHandleIntent(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29), but I'd need a count on the actual requests and not on the executed intents.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> It just occured to me, as the onStartCommand(...) method can be called from various asynchronous threads, that this might not be a thread-safe solution.

`onStartCommand()` is always called on the main application thread in any service. You cannot be called with `onStartCommand()` in two threads simultaneously.

Comment: Learning new things every day. Thanks!

Comment: @digitizedx: Is **what** not thread safe? `onStartCommand()` is, insofar as it is only ever called on the main application thread.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. It is probably unrelated this question, I am also having a similar problem, I am starting the service from broadcast receiver. At one point I get two broadcast simultaneously. I see the onCreate() of the contentprovider associated with the application is called twice. So I am doubting that startService is not threadsafe because it is trying to create the service twice.